# TypeError: Object.entries is not a function at MERN-CLI installation

Tags: javascript, backend, mern

I am currently testing around with the MERN Stack as an alternative to the LAMP Stack since the market is apparently shifting. Unfortunately, I ran into the biggest known motivation killer in programming; The setup fails:

When running `npm install` inside the directory I created with `mern init initial_app` before, I am constantly getting the same Error: `TypeError: Object.entries is not a function`.

Here is the error in the associated log file:

```
694 verbose stack TypeError: Object.entries is not a function
694 verbose stack     at Object.report [as install] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-audit-report\reporters\install.js:27:31)
694 verbose stack     at Promise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-audit-report\index.js:18:46)
694 verbose stack     at report (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-audit-report\index.js:17:10)
694 verbose stack     at Object.printInstallReport (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\audit.js:87:10)
694 verbose stack     at Object.Installer.printInstalledForHuman (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:847:31)
694 verbose stack     at Bluebird.try.then (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:774:19)
694 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
694 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
694 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
694 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
694 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
694 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
694 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
694 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
694 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
694 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
695 verbose cwd D:\MERN\initial_app
696 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
697 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
698 verbose node v6.11.1
699 verbose npm  v6.0.0
700 error Object.entries is not a function
701 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Do you know what is causing the error here or have you experienced a similar situation regarding the mern-cli? If this is some kind of issue directly related to the mern-cli, I would not mind, reposting this to the respective Github page.

Thank you in advance, J0nny

Comment: Upgrade to Node.js 7.0.0 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade node to a newer version.  This isn't supported in Node 6.  For full support you probably want to be on at least 8.x+

Comment: Consider marking answers correct to help future viewers, you have a lot of unclosed questions - this won't help people answer your questions in future. @J0nny